# Access Form filter with multiple items in a field

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

On My query I have a field with multiple Names. Some are Managers and some are Auditors.

1. On my form, I added a field with two Items , Managers and Auditors. So, when I select Managers I would like to filter my subform and query with 5 names in my record and if I select Managers, I would like to be able filter my form/query with 3 names in my record.

below is my vba code, but it's not working,

```
Private Sub cboAuditor_AfterUpdate()

    strManagers = "<>'Steven' And <>'Lisa' And <>'Christopher' And <>'Ronda' "
    strAuditors = "'Steven' Or 'Lisa' Or 'Christopher' Or 'Ronda' Or 'Amber'"


        If Me.cboAuditor = "Managers" Then
            strAnalystFilter = "[Created By] = '" & strManagers & "'"

        ElseIf Me.cboAuditor = "Auditors" Then            
           strAnalystFilter = "[Created By] = '" & strAuditors & "'"

        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that syntax - and who you wish to include or not is not clear. But try this for a start and then modify:

```
Private Sub cboAuditor_AfterUpdate()

    strManagers = "'Steven','Lisa','Christopher','Ronda'"
    strAuditors = "'Steven','Lisa','Christopher','Ronda','Amber')"

    If Me.cboAuditor = "Managers" Then
        strAnalystFilter = "[Created By] Not In (" & strManagers & ")"
    ElseIf Me.cboAuditor = "Auditors" Then            
        strAnalystFilter = "[Created By] In (" & strAuditors & ")"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! but My filter still not moving :(